# How to share ms access concurrently with AJAX and FFMPEG

Tags: ajax, multithreading, ms-access, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I have a .NET website that uses MS Access database on the back end.  I know SQL Server is better, but I'm stuck with MS Access for now.  I'm able to connect and do inserts, updates, etc. with no problem, except for one particular scenario:  when I execute a ffmpeg.exe executable, it runs a process converting a file for about a minute and updates the database every second.  While ffmpeg is running, I have javascript executing ajax XMLHttpRequest post's, at the same time, to get the updated value(s) so I can update a progress bar.

The problem is that the the XMLHttpRequest's are not executing until the ffmpeg is completed, but I need them to run concurrently at the same time.  Here's a shortened example, in pseudocode, with numbers to make it easy-to-read, of what is happening:

```
...ffmpeg started...
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //1
ffmpeg update 1
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //2
ffmpeg update 2
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //3
ffmpeg update 3
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //4
...ffmpeg ended...
ajax.onreadystatechange... //1
ajax.onreadystatechange... //2
ajax.onreadystatechange... //3
ajax.onreadystatechange... //4
```

But what I need to happen is this:

```
...ffmpeg started...
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //1
  ajax.onreadystatechange... //1
ffmpeg update 1
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //2
  ajax.onreadystatechange... //2
ffmpeg update 2
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //3
  ajax.onreadystatechange... //3
ffmpeg update 3
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //4
  ajax.onreadystatechange... //4
...ffmpeg ended...
```

I suppose that ffmpeg is locking up the database and preventing the ajax read's from executing, but they should be happening concurrently and taking turns accessing the database.  My connection string, in both updates, reads, etc. is the following:  Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyDatabase.accdb;.

Each javascript post looks like this:

```
var obj = { filename: fName };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
var url = 'Handler_Uploads.aspx?command=checkconversion&filename=' + fName;
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", url, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");    
ajax.send(myJSON);
```

I should mention that I've tried adding "Mode=Share Deny None;" to the connection string, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:  it was in the 'ffmpeg started' step.  Evidently, when that was called, it was executing synchronously, instead of asynchronously, and was preventing other XMLHttpRequest's from executing until the 'ffmpeg started' stopped.  Once I corrected the server code to execute the 'ffmpeg started' step asynchronously, the other XMLHttpRequest's executed as expected.